# Removing duplicates and NULL in Special character separated String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

*Before starting my question, I would definitely agree that this is bad design and now we are trying to repair this. Going forward, for all the new data, we are going to follow `1NF`*

---[**Here is the fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5235fb1f2e2a56342151dec4472a5dfc) ----

*I have a table data like this.*

[image]

I want to remove the repeated values and 'NULL' values.

*Expected output:*

```
180;;200
AMD;;SRD
ASE;;GIF;;TED
1
AMD;;SRD
null
LKG;;This is text with space
```

*What i have tried:*

```
WITH Splitted AS
(

    select id,attr,val
     ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(replace(val,'NULL',''),';;','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheParts
    from test where val like '%;;%' 
)
SELECT 
      Replace(STUFF(
          (TheParts.query
          ('
          for $x in distinct-values(/x/text())
            return <x>{concat(";;", $x)}</x>
          ').value('.','varchar(250)')),1,2,''),' ','') AS ColumnB
FROM Splitted;
```

*Current output*

```
180;;200
AMD;;SRD
ASE;;GIF;;TED;;ASE  --problem here
1
AMD;;SRD
null
LKG;;Thisistextwithspace -- problem here
```

i'm losing space between the string as well. And for some cases the value gets repeated. I think because of extra spaces at the end. How to fix this? Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: your `Replace` removes all the spaces

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to do. Shame `normalize-space` doesn't exist in SQL Server's available XQuery functions

Comment: @MartinSmith , yes, my `replace` was removing. But i couldn't find how to remove only those trailing and leading spaces. Now i could do with Larnu's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using an older version of SQL Server you have no access to `STRING_SPLIT` or `STRING_AGG`. The former, however, isn't particularly helpful here as Microsoft ***still*** haven't implemented ordinal positions into the function and it only supports a single character splitter.

I am going to instead use [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) which *does* support ordinal positions. Unfortunately, it too only supports a single character splitter, so I have replaced the double semi-colon (`;;`) delimiter with a pipe (`|`); as i assume that won't appear in your data.

2012 also doesn't have `TRIM`, so you'll need to use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` to trim the values.

Finally, you can use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method to "re-aggregate" the string:

```
WITH Splits AS(
    SELECT t.id,
           t.attr,
           DS.ItemNumber,
           NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(DS.Item)),'NULL') AS Item,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.id, LTRIM(RTRIM(NULLIF(DS.Item,'NULL'))) ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) AS RN
    FROM dbo.test t
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(REPLACE(t.val,';;','|'),'|') DS) --DelimitedSplit8K only supports a one character splitter
SELECT t.ID,
       t.attr,
       STUFF((SELECT ';;' + S.Item
              FROM Splits S
              WHERE S.ID = t.ID
                AND S.RN = 1
              ORDER BY S.ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS NewVal
FROM dbo.test t;
```

*Edit: Forgot about the duplicates. I use `ROW_NUMBER` in CTE to number the values, and then filter in the `WHERE` of the `FOR XML PATH` subquery. `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` won't work there, as then `ItemNumber` wouldn't be allowed to be used in the `ORDER BY`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot once again for your timely help @Larnu. Yes, I don't have `|` in my values.